# SQL - convert string to maths expression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column that contains arithmetic expressions, say `'1+2+3'.`
How (if?) can I make SQL interpret the string as a statement?

```
"SELECT 1+2+3" will result in 6.
Any possible way to SELECT CAST(CONVERT(WHATEVERVOODOOMAGIC('1+2+3'...
```

to get 6 without creating stored functions?

Played with

```
EXEC('SELECT'...)
```

but still no success.

Comment: It can be done, but why do you want to do this within SQL?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? (you should add the specific RDMBS tag to your question)

Comment: MS SQL 2008 R2. This needs to be done in SQL only - this condition I cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 SELECT [1+2+3]
```

it works

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tmp (col1 varchar(10))

insert into #tmp values ('1+2+3')

declare @dynamic varchar(1000);
select @dynamic = 'select ' + col1 from #tmp
execute (@dynamic)

drop table #tmp
```

Comment: because thats the syntax to execute a dynamic query in sql

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what I have asked.  Obviously this executes a dynamic query but **why did you choose that particular query** (i.e. the stuff that goes **inside** the brackets of the `execute` command) to solve this problem?

Comment: because that is what the user wants. He wants to run `SELECT 1+2+3` statement and wants the answer as `6`, I just gave him the way to do that

Comment: Good.  Now modify your post so that this is explained.

Comment: Both `SELECT 1+2+3` and `EXECUTE('SELECT 1+2+3')` give 6. That I pretty much understand. But my question is how can I do this with a _string_ written in existing column of the table?

Comment: In that case, you need to create dynamic sql to execute the string in the column. I have modified my answer with a example. See if that is what you want.